# Javascript function is corrupting my .png image

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a website and trying to upload an image to a local folder.  I am successfully uploading the image, but I get an error when I try to open the image.  Can anyone show me how to fix this problem?

Here is the error:
Could not load image'.PNG'. Fatal error reading PNG image file: not a PNG file.

Here is my partial:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Please Upload your Images</label>
    <br>
    <area href="./img" alt="this is a test">
    <br>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" ng-click="uploadImage()" id="uploadButton" multiple>
</div>
```

Here is my function:

```
$scope.uploadImage = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById("uploadButton");
    var text = document.querySelector("area");
    var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var name;

    input.onchange = function(e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      console.log("reader in CommandNewCtrl", reader);
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log("event", event);
        text.value = event.target.result;
        button.disabled = false;
      }
      name = e.target.files[0].name;
      console.log("name", name);
      reader.readAsText(new Blob([e.target.files[0]], {
        "type": "application/png"
      }));
    };

    button.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var blob = new Blob([text.value], {
        "type": "application/png"
      });
      console.log("blob", blob);
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = name;
      console.log("a.download", a.download);
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      console.log("a.href", a.href);
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      text.value = "";
      input.value = "";
      button.disabled = true;
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
};
```

Comment: What happens if you change to `image/png` instead of `application/png` as the  proper mime type?

Comment: Where is image uploaded to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readAsText` is not appropriate for binary data such as images. Try using [readAsArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) or [readAsDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) instead.

See [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL#Example) that shows a preview image from a file selector.

You should also change the mimetype to `image/png` as Mark Schultheiss suggested.

Comment: Yup, change to the method you suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Samuel and Mark!  This code is working!

```
input.onchange = function(e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      console.log("reader in CommandNewCtrl", reader);
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log("event", event);
        text.value = event.target.result;
        button.disabled = false;
      }
      name = e.target.files[0].name;
      console.log("name", name);
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(new Blob([e.target.files[0]], {   //was readAsText
        // "type": "application/png"
            "type": "image/png"

      }));
    };

    button.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var blob = new Blob([text.value], {
        "type": "image/png"
      });
      console.log("blob", blob);
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = name;
      console.log("a.download", a.download);
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      console.log("a.href", a.href);
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      text.value = "";
      input.value = "";
      button.disabled = true;
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
};
```